# Trying to insert stream_id from FileTable into SQL table that has a "stream_id" column to reference back to the FileTable, but it is not working

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert, dynamic-sql, filetable

I'm trying to add stream_id from SQL Server FileTable into the stream_id column in [category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO4UH.png) using the second insert statement in the code below. I am following the code of [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56506428/19853836) but after the stored procedure runs, stream_id column is still `NULL`. I do not know if the reason is that the value I get from GetPathLocator() function does not equal the path_locator column in the FileTable or there is something wrong with the stored procedure. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Ye4.png) is an image of the queried FileTable.

This is the stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpCategory_AddCategory] 
     @CategoryName nvarchar(100),
     @RelativeFilePath nvarchar(MAX),
     @Username nvarchar(100),
     @FileName nvarchar(1000),
     @Id int = 0 output

AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
     @attributes nvarchar(10),
     @tablename nvarchar(50),
     @filenameStr nvarchar(1000),
     @relativeFP nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @filenameStr = @FileName
    SET @relativeFP = @RelativeFilePath;
    SET @attributes = N' * '
    SET @tablename = N'FileData '
    SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + CHAR(39) + @filenameStr + CHAR(39) + N', ' + @attributes + 
               N' FROM ' + N'OPENROWSET(BULK ' + CHAR(39)+ @relativeFP + CHAR(39) + ', SINGLE_BLOB)' + N' AS ' + @tablename
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[LibraryTable] ([name],[file_stream])
    EXEC(@sql)

    DECLARE @FileTableRoot varchar(1000);
    SELECT @FileTableRoot = FileTableRootPath('dbo.LibraryTable');  
    INSERT INTO dbo.[Category] (categoryName, stream_id, userId)
    VALUES(@CategoryName, (SELECT stream_id
                            FROM dbo.LibraryTable
                            WHERE path_locator = GetPathLocator(CONCAT(@FileTableRoot, @relativeFP))) , (SELECT id FROM dbo.[User] WHERE dbo.[User].username = @Username))
    
    Select @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END
```

This is the execution of the stored procedure:

```
USE [LibraryMS]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @Id int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SpCategory_AddCategory]
        @CategoryName = N'Encyclopedia',
        @RelativeFilePath = N'C:\Users\mahmo\Desktop\NTNU_Backup\Code_Exercises\c_sharp_exercises\PROJECT_library_management_system\Images\Images\Encyclopedias.jpg',
        @Username = N'mamo_00',
        @FileName = N'Encyclopedias.jpg',
        @Id = @Id OUTPUT

SELECT  @Id as N'@Id'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Seems like an odd way to get the `stream_id`. Why not just put the insert within the dynamic SQL, along with an `OUTPUT` clause, then pass it back. `SET @sql = N'DECLARE @tmp TABLE (stream_id uniqueidentifier); INSERT INTO [dbo].[LibraryTable] ([name],[file_stream]) OUTPUT inserted.stream_id INTO @tmp (stream_id) SELECT ''' + @filenameStr + N''', bulkcolumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @relativeFP + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS FileData; SELECT @stream_id = stream_id FROM @tmp;'; DECLARE @stream_id uniquidentifier; EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@stream_id uniqueidentifier OUTPUT', @stream_id = @stream_id;`

Comment: Also the value you are passing for `@RelativeFilePath` is not a relative file path, so concatting it with `@FileTableRoot` doesn't make much sense

Comment: I tried to implement your method but i still get the same results 
` 
DECLARE @stream_id uniqueidentifier; 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@stream_id uniqueidentifier OUTPUT', @stream_id = @stream_id; 

INSERT INTO dbo.[Category] (categoryName, stream_id, userId) VALUES(@CategoryName, **@stream_id**, (SELECT id FROM dbo.[User] WHERE dbo.[User].username = @Username)) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem while i was in the process of dismantling my stored procedure to see exactly why it did not work. What i did was creating two additional stored procedures, one to handle loading files into the FileTable and one to insert the data into the Category table. I did this to see if any of those part where fault in my stored procedure not working. But while in the process of doing this my [dbo].[SpCategory_AddCategory] actually worked.

In conlusion i can not say why worked, it just did.

This is the main stored procedure that handles both inserting files into FileTable and inserting into Category table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpCategory_AddCategory] 
     @CategoryName nvarchar(100),
     @Username nvarchar(100),
     @RelativeFilePath nvarchar(MAX),
     @FileName nvarchar(1000)
  
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    EXEC dbo.spLibraryTable_LoadFilesIntoFT @RelativeFilePath = @RelativeFilePath, @FileName = @FileName;

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DECLARE @stream_id uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @FileTableRoot varchar(1000);
    DECLARE @fullpath nvarchar(1000);   
    DECLARE @Id int;

    
    SELECT @FileTableRoot = FileTableRootPath();
    
    SELECT @fullpath = @FileTableRoot + ft.file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath()  
    FROM [dbo].LibraryTable  AS ft
    WHERE name = @FileName; 

    SET @stream_id = (SELECT stream_id FROM dbo.LibraryTable WHERE path_locator = GETPATHLOCATOR(@fullpath));
    
    EXEC dbo.spCategory_InsertIntoCategory @stream_id, @fullpath, @Username, @CategoryName, @Id = @Id OUTPUT
    
END
```

Here is dbo.spLibraryTable_LoadFilesIntoFT

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLibraryTable_LoadFilesIntoFT] 
     @RelativeFilePath nvarchar(MAX),
     @FileName nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
     @attributes nvarchar(10),
     @tablename nvarchar(50),
     @filenameStr nvarchar(1000),
     @relativeFP nvarchar(MAX)
    
    SET @filenameStr = @FileName;
    SET @relativeFP = @RelativeFilePath;
    SET @attributes = N' * ';
    SET @tablename = N'FileData ';


    SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + CHAR(39) + @filenameStr + CHAR(39) + N', ' + @attributes + 
               N' FROM ' + N'OPENROWSET(BULK ' + CHAR(39)+ @relativeFP + CHAR(39) + ', SINGLE_BLOB)' + N' AS ' + @tablename;
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[LibraryTable] ([name],[file_stream])
    EXEC(@sql);

END
```

Here is dbo.spCategory_InsertIntoCategory

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCategory_InsertIntoCategory] 
    @stream_id uniqueidentifier,
    @fullpath nvarchar(1000),
    @Username nvarchar(100),
    @CategoryName nvarchar(100),
    @Id int = 0 output
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    
    INSERT INTO dbo.[Category] (categoryName, stream_id, userId)
    VALUES(@CategoryName, @stream_id , (SELECT id FROM dbo.[User] WHERE dbo.[User].username = @Username));
    
    Select @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Comment: `GetPathLocator(CONCAT(@FileTableRoot, @relativeFP))` and the second variable was not a relative path, changed to use the value coming from `SELECT @fullpath = @FileTableRoot + ft.file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath()` so it's understandable it didn't work before and works now.

Comment: @Charlieface You are right my pathname was confusing and i was using wrong path to get the `path_locator`. Although when i changed the path, it still did not work. I changed the path before i even made those extra stored procedures which puzzeled me why it did not work (since the code was made as logical as possible) and when i ran the code outside of the sp (in like a new query window) the code worked, but when i ran the code in the sp it did not work, and i was going crazy because it didnt make sense. But finally it worked out.